# CSS Position Absolute failed when using vh and vw unit

Tags: html, css, responsive

i am using the following code to mask a background video in a svg text with some other text around. My problem is that the white texts do not keep their position on resizing, although I work with `vh` and `vw` units. And the white heading and the white description do not have the same distance to the MASK.

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
.font-serif font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
.font-mono font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.headline-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 1.4%;
}

.headline {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.description-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70vh;
  left: 1.4%;
}

.description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: url(#mask);
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover; 
}

.mask-text {
  text-anchor: start;
  font-size: 16vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="headline-wrapper">
      <h3 class="headline">Headline</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="description-wrapper">
      <p class="description">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video class="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted loop autoplay="true"></video>
      <svg><clipPath id="mask"><text class="mask-text" x="2%" y="55vh">MASK</text></clipPath></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

my goal is to keep the white texts in its position, always at the same distance from the MASK text, so that it is responsive. 
How can this be achieved? Is there an only-css solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the elements around the center then offset them using translate. I will also consider mask instead of clip-path to easily make it at the center.

You may need to adjust the `viewBox` of the SVG when changing the `font-family`

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.headline-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-180%);
  left: 1.4%;
}

.headline {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.description-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(120%);
  left: 1.4%;
}

.description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.video-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
   -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -10 70 12"><text font-family="monospace">MASK</text></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
           mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -10 70 12"><text font-family="monospace">MASK</text></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;

}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display:block;
}

.mask-text {
  text-anchor: start;
  font-size: 16vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="headline-wrapper">
      <h3 class="headline">Headline</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="description-wrapper">
      <p class="description">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video class="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted loop autoplay="true"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Looks Good, but the MASK Text not follow the `font-family` could whe change this?

Comment: @NiklasGrewe you can change this inside the SVG, you will find a font-family there. I didn't do it to keep only the relevant part of the code

Comment: one question: How can i set a `max-width` or `max-height` for the mask? When i add `max-height` to svg element is not working

Comment: @NiklasGrewe the mask behave like a background, you cannot set max-height/width to it, you need to manipulate `mask-size`\ `mask-position` ... you can ask another question with detail if you want an accurate answer

Comment: i create another question for this casse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990205/how-can-i-set-a-max-values-to-a-css-mask